# Method 'Run' of object IWshShell3 failed

Tags: excel, vba, windows-xp

I am trying to extract the stuffs from an archive with password. It worked seamlessly in Win 7 but gives this error in Win XP "Method 'Run' of object IWshShell3 failed in VBA"

```
Sub extractTemp()
Dim path$
path = Environ("AppData") & "\HGR\"
zipFile = path & "myArchive.7z"
Password = "lorem"
Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Sh.Run path & "\7za.exe e -aoa -r " & qq(zipFile) & " -o" & qq(Environ("temp") & "\ *") & " -p" & qq(Password), 0, True
End Sub
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function
```